# CMake: Linking a static library from a subdirectory to an executable in another subdirectory

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a project that uses both my own code and external code that needs to be compiled. My file tree is as follows.

```
PROJECT_ROOT
 |--CMakeLists.txt
 |--src
     |--CMakeLists.txt
     |--B1.cpp
     |--B1.h
     |--B2.cpp
     |--B2.h
     |
     |--ext
     |   |--CMakeLists.txt
     |   |--outside_module
     |   |   |--CMakeLists.txt
     |   |   |--A1.h
     |   |   |--A1.cpp
     |
     |--exe
         |--CMakeLists.txt
         |--runnerA.cpp
         |--runnerB.cpp
```

I have pasted the structure of my CMakeList.txt files below. The problem that I am having is that my `runnerA` executable gives me a bunch of undefined reference errors to symbols defined in A1.h and A1.cpp. For some reason, however, CMake is unable to find my library `A` when trying to link to the executable `runnerA`.

I included the rest of the code, because it compiled just fine. I am able to build executable `runnerB` with no problem. I have deduced that `runnerB` works because the source files are in my `src` folder, which is a parent to my `exe` folder, and thus the `B` library scope includes `exe`.

**How can I let CMake know where to find my `A` library, so that it can find it when linking it to `runnerA` in `src/exe`?**

---

**PROJECT_ROOT**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(MyProject)

add_subdirectory(src)
```

**PROJECT_ROOT/src**

```
find_package(Module REQUIRED)

# CREATE LIBRARIES
add_library(
    B
    B1.cpp B1.h
    B2.cpp B2.h
)

# GROUP LIBRARIES TOGETHER
set(
    B_LIBS
    B
    ${Module_LIBS}
)


# INCLUDE DIRECTORIES
set(
    B_INCLUDES
    .
    ${Module_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

# ASSIGN INCLUDES TO LIBRARY
target_include_directories(
    B PUBLIC
    ${B_INCLUDES}
)


add_subdirectory(ext)
add_subdirectory(exe)
```

**PROJECT_ROOT/src/ext**

```
add_subdirectory(outside_module)
```

**PROJECT_ROOT/src/ext/outside_module**

```
find_package(Boost COMPONENTS
    filesystem
    system
    log
    thread
    REQUIRED)

# ADD DEFINITIONS
add_definitions(-DBOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK) # Necessary to compile A with log shared libraries (instead of static)

# DEFINE LIBRARY
add_library(
    A
    A1.cpp A2.h
)

# LINK LIBRARIES
set(
    A_LIBS
    A
    ${Boost_FILESYSTEM_LIBRARY}
    ${Boost_LOG_LIBRARY}
    ${Boost_SYSTEM_LIBRARY}
    ${Boost_THREAD_LIBRARY}
)

# INCLUDE DIRECTORIES
set(
    A_INCLUDES
    ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
```

**PROJECT_ROOT/src/exe**

```
# DEFINE EXECUTABLES
add_executable(runnerB runnerB.cpp)
add_executable(runnerA runnerA.cpp)


##################
# LINK LIBRARIES
##################
target_link_libraries(
    runnerB
    ${B_LIBS}
)

target_link_libraries(
    runnerA
    ${A_LIBS}
)

target_include_directories(
    runnerA PUBLIC
    ${A_INCLUDES}
)

# INSTALLATION
install(TARGETS runnerB DESTINATION bin/)
install(TARGETS runnerA DESTINATION bin/)
```

Comment: You need to link your executable to A: `target_link_libraries(runnerA A)`.

Comment: @arrowd: I did. Typo in my code for the `PROJECT_ROOT/src/exe` section. Fixed now

Comment: @arrowd: Also, that being said, I really think it's an issue of scope. As my CMake commands work for for runnerB

Comment: Downvoter--what's up? It's not a duplicate and already has an accepted answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right, you set that `${A_LIBS}` variable in nested CMakeLists.txt. The solution is to use [set() command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set) with `PARENT_SCOPE` or `CACHE` keyword.

Comment: What happens, as in my case, when I need "grandparent" scope?

Comment: Use `CACHE`, this would create an entry in `CMakeCache.txt`, and thus your variable will be global.

Comment: And don't forget `FORCE` in this case too!

Comment: `CACHE` made it work. This seems like it's perhaps poor practice, no? Is there a more elegant way to do this than passing these groups through the CMakeCache.txt file?

Comment: Not necessarily. All these `FindFoo.cmake` modules are actually doing exactly this. It is just they are usually called in the same `CMakeLists.txt`, where `${FOO_LIBRARIES}` are used, but internally they just set cache variables. Take a look at https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/mark_as_advanced.html also.

Comment: That makes sense in hindsight actually, having spent a lot of time searching through the cache. This did the trick. Thanks for the help!